# Why do some who don't have KTN (Known Traveler Number) get TSA Pre Check on their boarding pass?

Tags: tsa-precheck

Why do those who I book to travel with me get the TSA Pre Check on their boarding pass when only I have the KTN? Even a stranger, a co-worker whom I had never met in person, got it. My wife and her friend got it when booking their own flights and traveling without me and neither of them have a KTN.

Answer (score 3):

TSA can grant pre-check to anyone on any given flight, whether they're a member of the program or not, based on their own internal criteria.  (There is [currently a bill in Congress](https://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-news/tsa-precheck-bill-ban-non-members) that would end this practice and restrict it to members only.)

The fact that they are traveling with a registered member may or may not have been a factor.  As far as I know, TSA doesn't reveal publicly what factors are considered.

Comment: Some people who are given precheck are even ineligible to apply for it.