# Randomly Selected TSA Pre-Check

Tags: tsa-precheck

I do not travel frequently.  Have not flown for two years.  Previously, I was randomly selected by the TSA based on their own criteria for TSA Pre-Check.  I have never applied for it, it just always showed up on my boarding pass.  What are the chances of a person being randomly selected after not traveling for two years?  Can I somehow obtain my KTN from the airline I traveled with in the past?

Comment: How old are you? I know seniors get TSA pre on their passes even without signing up for it

Comment: Were you traveling with someone who had Pre-Check? My partner (and kids but that's a known thing) would automatically get pre-check if we were travelling together.

Comment: @littleadv I'm not sure that's correct. I don't find a source saying seniors get Pre-Check automatically at age 75.. While [TSA provides slightly expedited screening for those over 75](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/special-procedures/screening-passengers-75-and-older) (shoes and light jackets may be left on), at least one [secondary source](https://community.southwest.com/t5/Check-In-Boarding/Rules-for-seniors-getting-TSA-Pre/td-p/82384) says the senior must still use the non-Pre-Check security line.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I know my parents got TSE Pre on their boarding passes and they're not even Americans.

Comment: When was "previously?" TSA had a program called "managed inclusion" that brought non-precheck members into the lanes based on unknown criteria, but that program began to be phased out in 2015 and reportedly ended sometime around 2018/2019. If you got the Precheck indicator on your boarding pass randomly back then under managed inclusion, you likely won't get it anymore unless you're a member or otherwise eligible (Global Entry/NEXUS/SENTRI, holder of a Department of Defense ID, HME or TWIC holder).

Comment: @littleadv A mystery. [This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122295/why-do-some-who-dont-have-ktn-known-traveler-number-get-tsa-pre-check-on-thei?rq=1) is related.